# How to use textplot() or any other baseR labeling function for avPlots?

Tags: r, plot, label, linear-regression

I am looking at the association between Worldwide Governance Indicators (WGI) and Yale's Environmental Performance Index (EPI) amongst a sample of 101 developing countries.

I'm trying to plot a 'partial regression plot' using the car package avPlot() function to visualise the association between Government Effectiveness (GE.EST) and the response variable (EPIScore2018). I want to label each point, using the iso3c codes, so I can choose a few countries to have as case studies but the labels are overlaying each other. The image link is the result I have from the code below.

```
lm.3 <- lm(EPI2018Score ~ GE.EST + lied_dummy + trade_log + log(NY.GDP.PCAP.CD) + resource_rents_log + log(PopDensity), data = wb_epi_df)
```

[s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmV1h.png)

```
avPlot(lm.3, variable = "GE.EST", 
   id=list(n=51, cex=1, col=carPalette()[1], 
           col.lines = carPalette()[2], location="lr"))
```

How do I prevent label conflict within the avPlot() id command?

Comment: There's a function in pkg:plotrix that will prevent labels from overlapping. And the plotrix::thigmophobe help pages also suggests "pointLabel in the maptools package and spread.labs in the TeachingDemos package". Whetehr the avPlot function from car package will allow the use of any of these remains unclear.

Comment: You might need to suppress labeling in the call to avPlot and then add labels with other base plotting functions.